# How do I make Visual Studios correctly highlight the class blue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

**Summary:** I'm trying to make my initialized classes (a class called DNA in this case) correctly highlighted blue within Visual Studios. When I try to initialize a class, the text is completely black for the class name. This is a C# script opened from Unity. DNA is correctly made within another script, and it produces no errors.

Problem:
[image: Unhighlighted Text (Problem)]

Goal:
[image: Highlighted Text (Goal)]

Let me know if I should provide any further information.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Using WhateverNamespaceDNAIsIn;` line at the top of the file?

Comment: @itsme86 I believe DNA is in the global namespace because I didn't define a namespace for it. I tried using the global:: operator, but it didn't highlight DNA blue. The class itself works, but I'm just interested in VS highlighting it blue when I define it like in that "Goal" screenshot.

Comment: Vector2, Vector3, Transform etc all aren't highlighted blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within **Unity**, go to **Edit**->**Preferences**->**External Script Editor** (At the top) Make sure to select visual studios (Browse for it's location if it's not listed automatically). Reopen your scripts and intellisense should work correctly.